# Updating jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, scroller

I have one problem with jQuery custom content scroller when I try to manipulate elements on page via ajax queries.

```
$(window).load(function(){
            $(".scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{
                    enable:true
                }
            });
        });
```

then I execute one ajax query to populate data from server

```
$.get(url, {'count':count, 'type':type}, function(data) {
            masBlock.append(data);
            $(".scroll").mCustomScrollbar("update");
            deleteHoliday();
            saveHoliday();

            $('.add-holiday').hide();
        })
```

but method "update" doesn't work and scroller doesn't resize. Please, what should I do to avoid this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `masBlock` variable define the `.scroll` element or an element inside it? 
Do you load images or plain text?

Instead of using the update method, you could try setting `updateOnContentResize` option parameter to `true` and see if that helps:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons:{
            enable:true
        },
        advanced:{
            updateOnContentResize:true
        }
    });
});
```